# fail to push large files in history of git

Tags: git, github

I found some similar questions with the same topic, but I could not resolve the problem with the them.

I am trying to push the existing repository to the github. There was some large files in the history that I removed with `rm`. Then I found I should do this with `git rm --cached file-to-remove.zip`. Now push try to upload those file and I get the following error. 
Thank you for any guide.

```
$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': a.ziaeemehr@gmail.com
Password for 'https://a.ziaeemehr@gmail.com@github.com': 
Counting objects: 4340, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2619/2619), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4340/4340), 286.38 MiB | 914.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4340 (delta 1941), reused 3133 (delta 1416)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1941/1941), done.
remote: warning: File functional_network/Wilson/human/data/png/movie.gif is 67.74 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 7ea19eadcd6ce640e452630eab3b8f7f
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File DiGraph/wang-buszaki/Shivakeshavan/src/ttt is 134.33 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File WC/connectome/Hagmann_2008/graph/no_delay/CPP/data_txt/1/timeseriesE.txt is 135.50 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File WC/connectome/Hagmann_2008/graph/no_delay/CPP/data_txt/timeseriesE.txt is 135.49 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/Ziaeemehr/my_neural.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Ziaeemehr/my_neural.git'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+huge+file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already read in your error message:

> remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
>   remote: error: Trace: 7ea19eadcd6ce640e452630eab3b8f7f
>   remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.

You might want to take a look at [Git LFS](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-git-large-file-storage/), if you need to add larger files to your repository (Besides that I'm not sure why a gif gets larger than 60MiB)

If you are searching on how to remove that file, you might take a look at this well written GitHub Help page: [Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/). It describes how to use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to remove a file completely from your repository's history:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch functional_network/Wilson/human/data/png/movie.gif' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be because your large files are still included in the previous commit. You could undo the commit and re-commit again or simply commit the current state of the repo, before trying to push again.